# Run pywin32 pythonservice.exe after create exe with cx-freeze

Tags: python-3.x, windows, python-3.7, cx-freeze, pywin32

I have a problem to install and run a Windows Service written in python 3.7 and with pywin32.

I use:
- a pipenv
- python 3.7
- cx-freeze 6.1
- pywin32 227

In my pipenv environ the Script runs and registered the service successful. But i got many problems when i freeze it with cx-freeze.

I figured out that i need to register the pythonservice.exe (pythoncom37.dll and pywintypes37.dll already in the dir with the exe and the python37.dll) on the pc where i run my service.exe (packed with cx-freeze).

On my dev pc i got this error if i want to register the pythonservice.exe:

> Registering the Python Service Manager...
>   Registration failed as sys.winver is not available or not a string

But every time i want to register the file (after freezing) on a VM with `pythonservice.exe -register` i got the error:

> C:\Users\USER.virtualenvs\PROJEKT_NAME\lib\encodings__init__.py", line 31, in 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'codecs'

And yes i `import codecs`.

---

Any ideas what i do wrong?
Or some hints?

Thank you!